# I cannot install Webpack using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, npm-install

Every time I use `npm install --save-dev webpack`, the command line throws an error saying this:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...it","version":"1.4.0"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\usman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-20T02_38_55_455Z-debug.log
```

I have tried rebooting my PC, install the webpack cli,  re-installing Node.js but nothing seems to work. Please help.

Comment: Did  you tried npm cache clean --force  ?

Comment: Yeah, I just found out and it worked perfectly fine, I was stuck for 6 hours and tried many things and this worked for me. Thanks.